# Maven handling Nexus exception

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

I have a project which has multiple sub projects (modules). More specifically this is an Eclipse project and has multiple features.

The issue is a feature might not need any changes for a release. For that reason I don't bump up the version number, but another feature in the same project might have changes. Since it is considered bad practise to re-deploy same versions I disabled that option in Nexus.

Now the actual problem occurs when I deploy. So deploying anything that has a new version number works fine, however when deploying old one I was sort of expecting maven to give warning that it already exits in repository and then skip it but turns out Nexus responds:

```
Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.
```

which then causes maven to fail the entire deployment process. The full error is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project xyz: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact xyz:target:2.5.8.0 from/to nexus (http://host/nexus/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://host/nexus/content/repositories/releases/x/targets/xyz/2.5.8.0/xyz-2.5.8.0.target. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Bad Request. -> [Help 1]
build   11-Sep-2015 07:09:57    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project abc: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact foo:abc:jar:2.5.8.0 from/to nexus (http://host/nexus/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://host/nexus/content/repositories/releases/bar/abc/2.5.8.0/abc.ocl-2.5.8.0.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Bad Request. -> [Help 1]
```

The question is, how can I handle this failure/exception? All I want is if it is already deployed then skip/ignore deployment of that artifact.

Answer (score 0):

See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 6.1. Maven Command Line Options, 6.1.8. Dealing with Failure](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-failure-option) or `mvn --help`:

```
-fae,--fail-at-end    Only fail the build afterwards;
                      allow all non-impacted builds to
                      continue
```

Comment: This works fine except then maven shows it as unsuccessful. Is there a way to suppress a particular failure as part of this -fae command?

Comment: @SarpKaya I'm not aware of any. It's called _fail_ at end, not _ignore-projects-with-errors_. You could use `-fn | --fail-never` but then you wouldn't recognize a "real" failure easily. You'd have to go through the build's output to search for those then.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally accepted best practice in Maven to use the same version across multi-module projects. I would just switch to that scheme and deploy each module even if it didnt really change internally.

If you dont want to do that, it would be better to break your project up into multiple projects that are built and released separately.

The only hacky workaround you can otherwise do is to set the skip property for the Maven deploy plugin for projects that have already been deployed. You will however have to manually manage that and therefore produce additional overhead and churn on your codebase. See more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/faq.html

Comment: I agree with that but business doesn't.